# Django DRF: ModelViewSet: How to show some foreign key properties along with id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
## MODELS

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    number_of_legs = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    ... (there are several other properties here)

class Breed(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        unique=True,
    )
    animal = models.ForeignKey(
        "Animal",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    ... (there are several other properties here)

class Pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    breed = models.ForeignKey(
        "Breed",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )



### SERIALIZERS


class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = "__all__"


class BreedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Breed
        fields = "__all__"


class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = "__all__"


## ModelViewset

class PetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Pet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PetSerializer
```

When I am trying to GET the list of pets I want something like this

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "rexy",
    "breed": 2, <-- foriengkey id
    --> HERE I ALSO WANT 
    "breed name"  <-- I dont want other properties of breed
    "animal name" <-- I dont want other properties of animal
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a source on a serializer field to tell it where to find the value from the model instance:

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    breed_name = serializers.CharField(source='breed.name', read_only=True)
    animal_name = serializers.CharField(source='breed.animal.name', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: But  then while posting, I dont these to be asked for

Comment: Try to add `required=False`

Comment: but then it will be used while saving

Comment: @Santhosh is this answer still relevant?

Comment: now its relevant. I have one more query in this regard. Can we use `read_only_fields` inside Meta. It didnt work for me. So `required=False` is not the right way.